# Type Hinting abstract class singleton

Tags: php, oop, phpstorm

How would one Type Hint a static singleton-returning method on an abstract class, which returns instances of the extending called classes?

For example, let's look at the following code:

```
<?php

abstract class Foo {

    /** @return Foo */
    public function init() {
        static $instance;

        if ( is_null($instance) ) {
            $class = get_called_class();
            $instance = new $class();
        }

        return $instance;
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {

    public $name = "Bar name";

}

class Baz extends Foo {

    public $age = 42;

}
```

My intention is for tools such as PhpStorm to understand that `Bar::init()` returns an object of type `Bar` and that `Baz::init()` returns an object of type `Baz`. Thus, for example, objects created from the `Baz::init()` method would auto-complete the `name` property but not the `age` property.

Obviously the current type hint `@return Foo` is wrong as the method will never return an object instance of an abstract class.

Comment: `@return Foo` is not wrong since the function returns an object which is an `instanceof Foo` even if that object is a child of `Foo` however if you want an accurate class hint you could probably get away with a `@return static` (maybe). Also this all is IDE hints so it's also up to your IDE to be smart enough to understand what it means.

Comment: @apokryfos: Thanks. In fact I had considered adding a PhpStorm tag to the question.

Comment: Why would you want your code to refactor itself every run?

Comment: @acoder: See the paragraph that starts `My intention...`, it addresses your question. Thanks.

Comment: @dotancohen classes are evil because they refactor, and add about 10% overhead by default. instead you should be using functions.

Comment: @acoder: Thank you for the viewpoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So `@return static` will work in this case for PHPStorm. *It is the easiest option* and will provide what you are looking for.

Optionally you can use the `@method` annotation against the class although this is very manual and needs to be done for each class. There is another strange thing with this method in PHPStorm where if you navigate to the `init()` method (ctrl+click or w/e) it will navigate to this annotation first. However this is how that looks:

```
/**
 * @method Bar init()
 */
class Baz extends Foo 
{
}
```

Where optionally as a final resort--and I really don't think you will need it but its here for completeness. Extend the method and add your return annotation as you would a normal method.

```
/**
 * @return Baz
 */
public function init() 
{
    return parent::init();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! In fact extending the method just to annotate it was a solution that I thought of but felt was way to hacky to implement.

Comment: Glad this helped. Also when working with `php7+` you may actually find yourself extending methods to change the type hints `init(): Baz`. Looks pointless but it does add runtime validation which is handy.

Comment: Obviously in php7 the following would not be valid: `init() : static`. Is there a solution for this using runtime hinting?

Comment: Sadly not, although I believe I have seen some RFC's that are trying to implement a workaround for this. In the case where I want to do this, I simply use `phpdoc` for the initial definition and no return type. Then you are free to add return types in the children, a mixture of both `phpdoc` and `php7` return types work best here. Currently you cannot override a return type even if its a class that inherits the original.

Comment: ‎‎‎‎Thank‎‎‎‎‎‎ you!‎‎‎‎‎‎‎   ‎‎  ‎‎    ‎‎

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
abstract class Foo {

    /** @return static */
   public function init() {
       static $instance;

       if ( is_null($instance) ) {
           $class = get_called_class();
           $instance = new $class();
       } 

        return $instance;
    }

}
```

This will probably require PhpStorm to be set up with PHP 5.3+ type hints to work.